# How do I blow away my attempt to resolve git conflicts

Tags: git, git-revert

I checked out 'production_branch' then did a merge of 'master_branch for_production_branch' there were massive conflicts.  'production_branch' has been deployed to production.  But the conflicts require a more experienced eye.  I need to get a critical patch (I will do it by hand) onto the production branch 'production_branch' so I can deploy.

```
git co 'production_branch'  # => 
lib/tasks/foobar.rake: needs merge
vendor/plugins/acts_as_syncable/lib/active_record/whatever.rb: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

and

```
git co 'master_branch for_production_branch'
lib/tasks/foobar.rake: needs merge
vendor/plugins/acts_as_syncable/lib/active_record/whatever.rb: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

How can I get back to 'production_branch' in my working directory so I can deploy a simple critical fix.

Answer (score 18):

You can use

```
git merge --abort
```

to abort your current merge action and revert to the situation before your started the merge. See [git merge documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) for more details.

Note that it will throw away any changes your made, but I suppose this is not a problem in your current situation...

Answer (score 9):

To blow away all the changes and set to prior to merge

```
git reset --hard commitsha
```

Here commitsha is the sha id of git commits. 
You can use `gitk` or `git log` to check state of your branch and figure out `commit_sha`

**Update**

or on branch `git reset --hard production_branch`

Comment: or just `git reset --hard HEAD`